# Blocks and objects

Tags: ruby, inheritance, super, ruby-1.9.3

I have an object like this

```
class SomeObject
  def initialize &block
    # do something
  end
end

class AnotherObject < SomeObject
  def initalize &block
    super
    # do something with block
  end
end
```

When `super` is called in `AnotherObject`, the block seems to be passed to `SomeObject`. Is this the right behaviour and is there away round it?

Comment: Don't you need this behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [rubyspec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec/blob/master/language/super_spec.rb#L188) this is the correct behaviour, even if you pass explicit arguments to super (i.e. `super('foo')`)

If you don't want to pass that block, you could just pass a block that does nothing, although this isn't quite the same thing (e.g. if the method changes its behaviour based on `block_given?`)

It appears that

```
super(&nil)
```

is a way to pass no block at all to super, although I couldn't find this in ruby spec.